# how to implement spring ldap in order to creat a method that access to the database and get user's roles before creating the user's session

Tags: java, spring, security, ldap

I am interested in using Spring Security LDAP in my project. We manage a list of documents, and each document is associated with a unique code representing a specific region.

User access to these documents is determined by their position. For example:

List of codes = {16; 48; 88}
User1 belongs to region 16 and holds position 'R,' allowing access exclusively to documents within region 16.
User2 is associated with region 48 and holds position 'N,' granting access to all documents across all regions.

User data is stored in LDAP. Upon user login, the application connects to the LDAP to retrieve all the user's information, including their position. Based on this position, the application sends a query to the database to obtain the list of codes allowed for that user. Subsequently, it creates a user session in Spring Security.

My question revolves around customizing this process using Spring LDAP, specifically concerning connecting to the database and retrieving the list of codes for each user before creating their session.

thank you

i would like to have an unswer to my problem

Comment: As stated the question is *way* too broad. This is not a question, this is a call out for help. However, the assignment is yours not ours. Sentences such as "i would like to have an unswer to my problem" are actually detrimental, just don't do that, we owe you absolutely nothing.

Comment: Note that pasting your question into ChatGPT 4 gives me quite nice results. It won't end with a directly usable application maybe but it does a good job explaining how you would start to solve this kind of problem. Then if you get stuck on something specific ask here, as ChatGPT is good at indicating a direction, but it's answers are certainly not always correct. Just like programming: choose the right tool for the job.